# Cron for job to run on first Sunday of the month

Tags: cron

I have a cron line for running  a command each first Sunday of the month, which looks like this:

```
0 19 1-7 * 0 command.sh


Minutes=0
Hours=19
Day= 1st to 7th
* = any month
0 = first day of the week (Sunday)
```

However, I had the surprise command.sh has run last Sunday (16th of June). Can anyone explain why my cron line is mistaken?

As an alternative, according to a [wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron), it is possible to use the "#" character to: "allow you to specify constructs such as "the second Friday" of a given month" . Is there an example available as how to use this to fit "the first Sunday of a given month"?

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
0 0 1 ? 1/1 SUN#1 *
```

it will run at 1 PM every first sunday of month

Comment: I think you added an extra 0 in the beginning. What does 1/1 mean? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your script will run at 19, the first seven days of each month (1-2-3-4-5-6-7) AND every Sunday.

This should works in your case:

```
0 19 1-7 * Sun [ "$(date '+\%a')" == "Sun" ] && /some/command
```

Answer (score 1):

Another expression which similar what **Haxis** mentioned below ,

```
0 19 1-7 * Sun  [ $(date +%d) -le 07 ] && /some/command
```

Answer (score 0):

This expression:

```
0 0 19 ? * 1#1 *
```

It will run on 19:00 on the first Sunday of every month.